# How to make my vscode font slant like sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

I use the **same font(Consolas)** in VScode and sublime. But it looks different in the same place:[image]

[image]

Here are my **sublime** settings:

```
{
    "auto_complete_selector": "source,text",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme-Darker.tmTheme",
    "font_face": "Consolas",
    "font_size": 12,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
    ],
    "theme": "Default.sublime-theme"
}
```

Here are my **vscode** settings:

```
    "materialTheme.accent": "Blue",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontWeight": 520,
    "editor.codeLensFontSize": 11,
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "debug.console.fontFamily": "Cascadia Mono",
    "python.showStartPage": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "todo-tree.tree.showScanModeButton": true,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
       "comments": "#7ea9eb"
```

My question is: How to make my vscode font slant like sublime?

Comment: use a different theme like `Winter Is Coming`, or customize your current theme, with TextMate scopes

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is exactly what I want!@rioV8

Comment: Can you provide the name of your color scheme? Thanks!

Comment: The vscode theme is `Material` ~@AnsonH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting), you can customize your theme color by using the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` rule in your user settings:

1. Open your `settings.json` and add the following rule first (replace `YOUR THEME NAME HERE` with the name of your color theme):

   ```json
   "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "[YOUR THEME NAME HERE]": {
         "textMateRules": []
      }
   }
   ```
2. Open a Python file of your choice. Then, open Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and run "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes"
3. Click on the keyword you wish make it italic. For example, we click on the `class` keyword to view its TextMate scopes. Copy the first TextMate scope ID as highlighted:

   [image: Textmate scope example]
4. Go back to your `settings.json`. Inside the `textMateRules` array, insert a new object with the `scope` property being the TextMate scope ID you just copied.

   ```json
   "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "[YOUR THEME NAME HERE]": {
         "textMateRules": [
           {
             "scope": "storage.type.class.python",
             "settings": {
               "fontStyle": "italic"
             }
           }
         ]
      }
   }
   ```
5. Save your `settings.json` and you should see the `class` keyboard in italics

   [image: Class being italic]

### Note

You can append more objects in the `textMateRules` array to make the font italic for more keywords. For example:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[YOUR THEME NAME HERE]": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "variable.parameter.function.language.special.self.python",
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": "storage.type.class.python",
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

```
maximetinu.identical-sublime-monokai-csharp-theme-colorizer
jprestidge.theme-material-theme
```

[image]

Also 'Winter is Coming' as it was mentioned previously